# When i use uiscrollview for zoom image it's blur.!

Tags: xcode

> uiimageview -> uiscrollview -> uiview

it's work find for zoom image with gesture method.

but after zoom in imaged. it's image bad quality.

How to reset best image quality depending on zoom in/out scale.

Answer (score 0):

The image quality is going to depend on the original pixel dimensions of the image. If you scale over 100%, you're going to notice a blurring of detail.